# Is there any way from PL/SQL to call synchronous and asynchronous to send the message to Kafka

Tags: oracle, asynchronous, apache-kafka, plsql, synchronous

I'm trying to research the way to apply Kafka in the legacy system which has an oracle form was written in PL/SQL function.
Can we have a mechanism to communicate with PL/SQL with Kafka and return the response object type in the database.(currently we are using AQ(Oracle AQ) in the system, but now I have to change to Kafka)

Example :

```
DECLARE
  response package.Object;
BEGIN
    response := package.callKafka('parameter');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('output: '||response.output);
END;
```

Comment: If you have any language that supports HTTP protocol, you may communicate with Kafka via [Confluent REST API](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/index.html). As long as `utl_http` package [was present in ancient 9i](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96612/u_http.htm), I suppose you may create a package to consume Kafka. As an alternative - Java stored procedure may also be deployed and exposed to PL/SQL. Please, update your question to include exact issue you have with coding.

Comment: Why you need to call from PL/SQL? Can you capture the same from target tables using a jdbc source connector?

Comment: Even if you could send the event, it's not clear what you expect `response` to be set to

Comment: Thank @astentx lead me to that way , let me try do it .

Comment: @Valath the system is using Oracle Form which writes PL/SQL, so I have to call from PL/SQL, about this point using JDBC source connector I think it is not related to my question.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I don't get your point , can you help me clearly?

Comment: do you have an option to persist the required data in a table in your PL/SQL logic and run a connect on top of it? That would be way clean, fast and scalable solution. What if the http to Kafka calls fails in the current design?! If your system is ok to fail if http fails, then you can do this way.

Comment: @Valath as the way you said I think it is change data capture with kafka connect , right?

Comment: @Luan yes, correct.

Comment: Kafka producers don't return responses beyond an ack from Kafka, so it's unclear what `response := package.callKafka` is supposed to be in your question. If you want to read data from the database into Kafka on any insert, update, or delete, Oracle GoldenGate or Debezium would be best (change data capture). If that cannot be done, then JDBC connector can read any data it can, but it'll miss knowing about delete/update events

Comment: @Onecricket, since Luan is generating from PL/SQL (from a programming context), he can generate the payload in any way as he wish and insert into a DB, may be he can have a flag for the operations column like I/U/D and run a connect over the table.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service that will populate a staging table in your database and use JDBC Source Connector to deliver those data to Kafka. Check this out. [enter link description here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/no-more-silos-how-to-integrate-your-databases-with-apache-kafka-and-cdc/)

Comment: Include code snippets to the answer, not everything on the internet stays there for indefinite period of time and the content of the link might be lost.